# Increasing the size of the mouse pointer in xterm

Tags: mouse, xterm

My mouse pointer switches from a big red arrow to a tiny double arrow as soon as I hover over an xterm window (when the mouse is over the title bar, all is good).      I've tried the myriad options on the web:

```
 a) increasing cursor size using the dconf-editor (org.gnome.desktop.interface)

 b) running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-size 48`       

 c) playing around in .Xresources:  I tried to set Xterm.pointerSize
```

but this didn't work, although

Has anybody got a solution to this other than the ones tried above?     I would have thought the solution was a setting in .Xresources since `Xterm.pointerShape:  sailboat` does set the mouse pointer shape as expected.

Thanks for any suggestions.